# Why string.Format produces such result?

Tags: c#, string

I have a line like the following in my code:

```
string buffer = string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture, "{0:N4}", 1008.0);
```

Why does `buffer` contain `1,008.0` (note comma) after executing this line?

Yes, I do guess that it's caused by my regional settings. The question is why they affect the result in this case?

EDIT:

Ok, I understand that it's completely my fault. It seems like I should have used [F format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k#FFormatString).

Comment: what is your regional setting...?

Comment: @gdoron ok, isn't CultureInfo.InvariantCulture should override this?

Comment: So what does InvariantCulture use as a thousands separator? Have you even checked it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `InvariantCulture` is loosely based on `en-US` which uses `,` as a thousands (group) separator.

Your result is what I would expect.

I also point you to the details of the [`N` numeric format specifier](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k.aspx#NFormatString):

> The numeric ("N") format specifier converts a number to a string of the form "-d,ddd,ddd.ddd…", where "-" indicates a negative number symbol if required, "d" indicates a digit (0-9), "," indicates a group separator, and "." indicates a decimal point symbol.

Answer (score 2):

You're using the **invariant culture**; your culture is irrelevant to this. For this, the N4 format means

```
-d,ddd,ddd,ddd...
```

That is, possible leading negative sign indicator and commas between thousands groups. For details see: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dwhawy9k#NFormatString

You can look at

```
NegativeSign
NumberNegativePattern
NumberGroupSizes
NumberGroupSeparator
NumberDecimalSeparator
NumberDecimalDigits
```

for the invariant culture. If you do, you'll see:

```
-
1
{ 3 }
,
.
2
```

Answer (score 1):

You are getting the comma because of "{0:N4}"

> n   ----- Number with commas for thousands -----  {0:n}
>   
> [Source:](http://blog.stevex.net/string-formatting-in-csharp/)

You will get the comma even without specifying InvariantCulture

```
Console.WriteLine(string.Format("{0:n4}", 1008.0));
```